# スクロールができません

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

下記のサイトを見てアプリのチュートリアルを作成しているのですが、なぜかスクロールできません。なぜでしょうか？

[[Swift] たった40行のUIScrollViewを使ったシンプルなチュートリアル画面サンプル - Qiita](https://qiita.com/osamu1203/items/a1a361f9ff00e93258e2)

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var pageControll: UIPageControl!
let pageNum = 4
let pageColors:[Int:UIColor] = [1:UIColor.red, 2:UIColor.yellow,3:UIColor.blue,4:UIColor.green]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(pageNum), height: self.view.bounds.height)
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.pageControll = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 50))
    self.pageControll.numberOfPages = pageNum
    self.pageControll.currentPage = 0
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageControll)

    for p in 1...pageNum {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(p-1), y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
        v.backgroundColor = self.pageColors[p]
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageProgress = Double(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.width)
    self.pageControll.currentPage = Int(round(pageProgress))
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

参照している記事では

```
self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(pageNum), self.view.bounds.height)
```

と `contentSize` を指定しているのに対して、あなたのコードでは

```
self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(pageNum), height: self.view.bounds.height)
```

と、`frame`しか指定していません。 
`frame`は親のViewから見た、そのビューの位置とサイズを表します。
なので、`scrollView.frame.width` が親Viewの横幅 `bounds.width` の数倍あるとすると、その scrollView は親Viewからはみ出して存在していることになります。

ScrollViewの中身のサイズを表すのは `contentSize` です。
`contentSize` を指定してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ああああほんとにありがとうございます！助かりました！